# Using Like on Join Field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, sql

Ok, so this has probably been asked by someone else out there somewhere but I can't find it via google or this stack, so...

I've got two tables from an SDE database (SQLServer Express 2008 r2) that are joined.  Now I'm trying to write a SQL Select by Attribute statement that tests if string from one table is like string from another table.

What I tried looks something like this:

```
"Database1.DBO.RoadsFC.Field1" LIKE '%Database1.DBO.RoadsAnnotation.TextString%'
```

I've tried various other combinations such as '%'+Database1.DBO.RoadsAnnotation.TextString+'%' but nothing I've tried has validated or run correctly (when it does work it's reading Database1.DBO.RoadsAnnotation.TextString as the string to test against, not the value of that field to test against).

Again, sorry if this's been asked, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: You need to remove the quotes around the field names or it will compare them as strings.

Comment: Database1.DBO.RoadsFC.Field1 LIKE %Database1.DBO.RoadsAnnotation.TextString% doesn't work either.  And neither does Database1.DBO.RoadsFC.Field1 LIKE '%Database1.DBO.RoadsAnnotation.TextString%'

Comment: '%'+Database1.DBO.RoadsAnnotation.TextString+'%' would be the way to query that field.

Comment: Rich suggests the MS SQL Server equivalent [of this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5225284/327026)

Comment: I agree with Rich's suggestion as to how it should look, but, for some reason Database1.DBO.RoadsFC.Field1 LIKE '%'+Database1.DBO.RoadsAnnotation.TextString+'%' doesn't work. As a matter of fact, when I try validating that it says there's an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a syntax that ESRI accepted, even though several of them appeared to be valid SQL syntax.  So, I ended up going the route of:

```
POSITION( Database1.DBO.RoadsAnnotation.TextString, Database1.DBO.RoadsFC.Field1) > 0
```

That did what I was wanting, and yes, ESRI makes you use "POSITION" regardless of what the actual string function is called in your database type.